# Dynamic flexbox on wrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I currently have the following

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to use flexbox to achieve the following layouts.

[Goal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDU8n.png)

Desktop works, mobile looks like this which is **INCORRECT**

[Current / Incorrect view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYGjA.png)

Comment: Use `@media` to have Dynamic flexbox on different screens

Comment: I think the goal is easier achieved with grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired look can be achieved in two ways either using `flexbox` or using a `grid` system. however, there are other lot's of methods but broadly these are the options with us.

And it's my suggestion to use a grid instead of flex if you want to achieve a dynamic flexbox

1. Method one (using `flexbox`)

```css
            .one ,.two,.three{
                height: 50px;
                width: 100px;
                margin: 20px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .main{
    
                display: flex;
            }
    
            @media only screen and (max-width: 368px) {
                .main{
    
                    display: block;
                    
    
                }
                .two{
                    position: absolute;
                    left:130px;
                    top:2px;
                    height: 120px;
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Method 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="main">
            <div class="one">Left</div>
            <div class="two">center</div>
            <div class="three">right</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. Method two (Recommended) using `grid` system

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 368px) {
  .item1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .item2 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item item1">Left</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">Center</div>
    <div class="grid-item item3">Right</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps you to achieve your goal, enjoy .

Comment: Thank you so so very much!!!!!!

Comment: Ah! always happy to help. Never mention just keep learning and sharing